# Upgrade Plone 2.5.5 to Plone 3.3.5

Tags: plone

I have a Plone installation at version 2.5.5.  I need to upgrade it to 3.3.5.  I'm not terribly familiar with Plone or Zope or Python.

This is in a windows 2008 R2 environment.  I have the install files for both versions and I'm not worried about breaking anything because everything is backed up a dozen times.

The steps I've taken so far:
1) backed up the old files
2) tried installing 3.3.5 to the same directory...received several DLL entry point errors at the end of the process.
3) had to restart the computer
4) after restart the version 2.5.5 plone controller was still working but the 3.3.5 controller was not.

Did I do something wrong?  The notes at www.plone.org/upgrade couldn't have been more unhelpful for my experience level.

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://plone.org/documentation/manual/upgrade-guide/

this is a good starting point, always.

Basically install Plone 3.3.X somewhere, install the same add-ons (and check compatibility, thus), copy the data.fs over and start plone 3. If it works, run the upgrade steps going in ZMI and following the noticies.

Comment: So the add-ons are the folders in the "product" directory, right?  To install them I just copy them over?

Comment: Accepted, for being "close enough"  I've found the documentation to be sparse at best...a lot of "what" but no "how" your single paragraph helped me more than 50+ pages of fluff.  The upgrade is still a failure, for some reason it doesn't like the macros but I'm further along than I was before.

Answer (score 0):

I think no Plone upgrade over major releases I have done went without complications.

My advice is to not upgrade in-place, but instead install the newer Plone version to another directory, create a new instance and copy the *Data.fs* file from the old site over to the new one. So you can at least compare your new to your old site, running side-by-side.

You then use the "migrate" product to update the database. Try using "dry-run" first. If you encounter errors during migration, try to disable the products that cause the error, and re-try.

That's -- roughly -- the advice from the Plone upgrade documents.

Comment: is the migrate product the plone_migrate that should be in the ZMI?

Comment: I was thinking of "portal_migration (Handles migrations to newer Plone versions)" which can be found in a plone site in the ZMI.

Sorry for taking so long.